# Implementation of ll(k) to ll(1) convertor !

Tags: compiler-construction, implementation

is there any implementation of ll(k) to ll(1) convertor ?

Answer (score 4):

IIRC; in general, no because some languages have ll(k) grammars but no ll(1) grammars. So unless I'm mistaken, not all ll(k) *can* be converted ll(1). However, that says nothing about the possibility of such a tool that will work the cases where it can be done.

---

the rule for left factoring is:

```
A := A B |
     A C |
     D |
     E ;
```

turns into:

```
A := (D | E) (B | C)*
```

or if you don't allow `()` groups and `*`:

```
A := D A'
     E A'

A' := B A' |
      C A' |
      nul ;
```

The trick becomes how to handle the translation of the action rules; if your language supports it, lambdas can be kinda handy there.

Comment: actually I'm looking for a piece of code that implements the handler for left recursion and Left-Factoring.i just want a simple example for a very simple grammar.